# reliable data transfer using udp in c

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing a socket program for reliable data transfer using udp. I am sending image file from client to the server in chunks of 1024 bytes. Below are my codes.They do work fine for large strings and smaller image files.But when I transfer image of 2.3 MB the server will only receive till 2 MB. Say if the total number ofpackets sent was 2271. The server will only receive till 2211 or less and will terminate abruptly. I am not knowing the reasson. Can you please explain me this? and suggest any solution.
Below is my client code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

char *itoa(long i,char *s,int dummy_radix)
{
    sprintf(s,"%ld",i);
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, int *argv[])
{
    int sock,length,n;
    struct sockaddr_in server,from;
    struct hostent *hp;
    long int packets =0;
    unsigned char buff[1024] = {0};


    // checking if hostname and the port address is provided //
    if(argc!=3)
    {
        printf("insufficient arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //create a socket//
    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    if(sock<0)
    {
        printf("error in opening socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //to get  the hostname of the system or the machine//
    hp= gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if(hp==0)
    {
        printf("Unknown host\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //build the server's IP address //
    bzero((char *)&server,sizeof(server));
    bcopy((char*)hp->h_addr,(char *)&server.sin_addr,hp->h_length);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port =  htons(atoi(argv[2]));
    length = sizeof(server);

    /*open the file that we wish to transfer*/
    FILE *fp = fopen("landscape.jpeg","rb");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("file open error");
        return 1;
    }
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END); //if exists read the size of the file 
    size_t file_size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET); 

    printf("size of the file is %d\n", file_size);

    /*find the number of packets*/

    packets = (file_size/1024)+1 ;

    /*send the number of packets to the server*/

     itoa(packets,buff,10);
    n= sendto(sock,buff,strlen(buff),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        if(n<0)
        {
            printf("error in sending message to the serveR");
        return 1;
    }




    /*Read data from file and send it*/
    int packetNum = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        /*First read file in chunks of  1024  bytes */

        int nread = fread(buff,1,1024,fp);
        //printf("Bytes read %d\n",nread);

        /*if read was success ,send data*/
        if(nread>0)
        {
            //printf("data sent now is %s\n",buff);
            n= sendto(sock,buff,strlen(buff),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
            printf("Sending %d, numBytes sent: %d\n", packetNum, n);
            packetNum++;
                    if(n<0)
                    {
                      printf("error in sending message to the server");
                  fclose(fp);
                  return 1;
            }

        }

        /*There is something tricky going on with the read..
         * Either there was error ,or we reached end of  file.
         */
        if(nread<1024)
        {
            if(feof(fp))
                printf("End of file\n");

            if(ferror(fp))
                printf("Error reading\n");
            break;
        }

    }
    close(sock);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

And my server code:

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock,length,fromlen,n;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct sockaddr_in from;
    char buf[1024];
    char file_buf[1024];
    int packets = 0;
    int received = 0;
    FILE *newfp;
    newfp = fopen("output.jpeg","wb");
    if(newfp==NULL)
    {
        printf("error opening the file\n");
            return 1;
    }   
    if(argc<2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "no port number specified\n");

        exit(0);
    }
    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if(sock<0)
    {
        printf("error in opening socket\n");
        return 1;
    }
    length = sizeof(server);
    bzero(&server,length);
    server.sin_family= AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    if(bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&server,length)<0)
    {
        printf("cannot bind\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fromlen  =sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        n = recvfrom(sock,buf,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&fromlen);
    if(n<0)
    {
            printf("recvfrom  error\n");
            return 1;
    }


    packets = atoi(buf);
    printf("Num packets expected: %d\n", packets);


    while(received<packets)
    {

        n = recvfrom(sock,buf,sizeof (buf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&fromlen);    

            //printf ("%d\n", n);
        printf("Packet num %d, numBytes received: %d\n", received, n);

        if(n<0)
        {
            printf("recvfrom  error\n");
            return 1;
        }
        //printf("%s",buf);
        if((fwrite(buf,1,n,newfp)) < n)
        {
            printf("error in writing to the file\n");
            return 1;
        }
        received++;

    }
    printf("Finished\n");
    fclose(newfp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to design a *protocol* to sit on top of UDP, which adds "reliability". Things like sequence numbers, and acknowledging of received packets. Or possibly research existing reliable file-transfer protocols on top of UDP and see if you can use one of them.

Comment: I see no code to make this reliable?..

Comment: Any specific reason for using UDP? If you use TCP for such scenarios, it will be more appropriate. Also, when there are too many requests, UDP server may be dropping requests without even you knowing that.  Adding sequence numbers, ack etc. are already handled in TCP

Comment: @NipunTalukdar Probably because the OP has read somewhere that UDP might have higher throughput (which it usually does). That's the reason UDP is often used for things like VOIP or Video streaming.

Comment: Which it usually does *without the reliability features*. Once you add those to the same standard as TCP, it is no better than TCP, by definition.

Comment: One suggestion is to use sniffer example tcpdump or wire shark and see is there any other packet drops. As others mentioned udp don’t retransmit the lost packets.

Comment: @EJP *Once you add those to the same standard as TCP, it is no better than TCP, by definition.*  Not true at all.  TCP has serious bandwidth-delay product issues because of the design of the underlying protocol - mostly related to the ack window. There's even a Wikipedia page on the problem:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product It's not that hard at all to beat TCP throughput over a long, fat connection with a custom UDP-based protocol.

Answer (score 1):

If a reliable transmission is expected then TCP socket is recommended.
But still, if you want to go with UDP sockets then you have to implement some sort of custom protocol where you have to wait till receiver has not acknowledged the reception of the packet.

In your client and server code, the client is blindly sending data to the server without caring for missed packets that is happening currently at the server side.

For a simple workaround, you can add a
`recvfrom(sock,buf,sizeof (buf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr));` immediately after
`n= sendto(sock,buff,strlen(buff),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr));`
in your **client.c** and
`n= sendto(sock,"ACK",strlen("ACK"),0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&fromlen);`
immediately after
`n = recvfrom(sock,buf,sizeof (buf),0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&fromlen);` in **server.c**

And you have to take care of handling the file properly because improper file handling can cause input and output file mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>        n= sendto(sock,buff,strlen(buff),0,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
> ```

You are transferring binary data, i.e. data which might contain `\0`. `strlen` cannot be used with binary data since it just determines the length of the data by looking for a `\0` inside the data. If a `\0` is in the middle of `buff` only the part until but not including this `\0` will be sent.

Apart from that:

> reliable data transfer using udp in c

While you are doing a data transfer you don't care about reliability at all. Packets might be reordered, duplicated or get lost and you will not notice it in most cases. UDP does not provide any reliability at all by its own, contrary to TCP.